# Oracle SQL, join tables taking the most recent date that does not exceed the reference date

Tags: sql, oracle, join, exists

In Oracle SQL (version 11g), I want to join table A with table B taking, from B, the row that has the most recent date but is not posterior to the date in A.
Example:

```
  table A                   table B
                             
   | year | id |       | year | id | val |
   | 2000 | 'a'|       | 2000 | 'a'|  1  |
   | 2000 | 'b'|       | 2001 | 'a'|  2  |
   | 2000 | 'c'|       | 1999 | 'b'|  1  |
   | 2003 | 'c'|       | 2003 | 'c'|  1  |
```

Desidered result is

```
| year |  id |  val  |
| 2000 | 'a' |   1   |
| 2000 | 'b' |   1   |
| 2000 | 'c' | (null)|
| 2003 | 'c' |   1   |
```

The trivial way to do this would be to join the two tables only on the column "id" and afterwards take the difference between the "year" from A and from B and keep only the rows where this difference is the smallest one for each "id" (using a window function). However this requires to first create a very big table, a very long operation.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this, maybe with a semijoin (=exist clause).

EDIT: it has been suggested to use LEFT JOIN LATERAL, which seems a fine solution but is available from Oracle version 12c. I need a solution that works for previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

A lateral join is handy for this:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a left join lateral
     (select b.*
      from b
      where b.id = a.id and b.year <= a.year
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) b;
```

EDIT:

You only want one column from `b`, so use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*, 
       (select b.val
        from b
        where b.id = a.id and b.year <= a.year
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) b
from a;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am in Oracle 11g, while LATERAL seems to be available only as from Oracle 12c (I will edit the question accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

In 11g use two step approach. In the first step join simple the two tables with the constraint on the years.

```
select a.id, a.year, b.year b_year, b.val
from a
left outer join b 
on a.id = b.id and a.year >= b.year
;

I       YEAR     B_YEAR        VAL
- ---------- ---------- ----------
a       2000       2000          1
b       2000       1999          1
c       2003       2003          1
c       2000
```

You will get in generall more rows per `a.id` and `a.year` so in the second step you filter only those rows with the lowest `b.year` - this is done with `ROW_NUMBER` and filter on the first row (`rn = 1`)

```
with ab as (
select a.id, a.year, b.val,
 row_number() over (partition by a.id, a.year order by b.year) as rn
from a
left outer join b 
on a.id = b.id and a.year >= b.year
)
select  
  id, year, val
from ab
where rn = 1

I       YEAR        VAL
- ---------- ----------
a       2000          1
b       2000          1
c       2000           
c       2003          1
```

As you mentioned, this approach could be prohibitive in case there are lot of *versions* to be joined. I'll simulate it by swapping you condition to get *a smalest higher year* (as there are not much lower years available).

Here sample data

```
create table a as
select 'a' id, 2000 year from dual union all 
select 'b' id, 2000 year from dual union all
select 'c' id, 2000 year from dual union all
select 'c' id, 2003 year from dual;

drop table b;
create table b as
select 'a' id, 1000 + rownum year, rownum val  from dual connect by level <= 1000000
union all
select 'b', 1000 + rownum year, rownum val  from dual connect by level <= 1000000
union all
select 'c', 2000 + rownum year, rownum val  from dual connect by level <= 2
;
```

Indeed the previous approach leads to a big number of intermediate results

```
with ab as (
select a.id, a.year, b.val
from a
left outer join b 
on a.id = b.id and a.year <= b.year
) 
select  count(*) from ab;

1998005
```

So what is the **alternative solution**?

Simple *pre-calculate the minimal highest year* in the first step

```
select a.id, a.year, min(case when b.year >= a.year then b.year end) b_year
from a
left outer join b 
on a.id = b.id 
group by a.id, a.year

I       YEAR     B_YEAR
- ---------- ----------
c       2000       2001
a       2000       2000
c       2003           
b       2000       2000
```

and use the pre-calculated table for the equi-join with `b`

```
with ab as ( 
select a.id, a.year, min(case when b.year >= a.year then b.year end) b_year
from a
left outer join b 
on a.id = b.id 
group by a.id, a.year)
select  
  ab.id, ab.year, b.val
from ab
left outer join b
on ab.id = b.id and ab.b_year = b.year;

I       YEAR        VAL
- ---------- ----------
c       2000          1
a       2000       1000
c       2003           
b       2000       1000
```

Comment: Though this is correct, this is basically what I hinted to as the obvious but impractical solution: it implies creating, in the first step, a very large table... which in my real application is too big to be manageable (the size of the table would be like 20 times table A). That's why I asked for a more efficient solution.

Comment: @Giuseppe Sorry I re-read the comment on this topic, I'll update/delete the answer

Comment: That's ok, I think it would still be fine to keep it, it may be useful for someone to see implemented the solution that I only hinted to.

Comment: @Giuseppe - I added the option how would I solve it for a large number of possible matches.